# WebDataRocks pivot table doesn't wrok with angularjs rest api

Tags: angularjs, webdatarocks

Here the div tag

```
<div wbr-pivot wbr-toolbar="true"  wbr-report="{ 'dataSource': { 'data':JSON.parse(WebDataRocks()),'dataSourceType': 'json'}}" >
</div>
```

here is the controller function

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope','serv', function ($scope,serv) {
    $scope.WebDataRocks = function () {
        return serv.WebDataRocks($scope.Filter).then(function (d) {
            return d.data;
        }, function (err) { });
    }
}]);
```

Please help!

Comment: You can't pass a promise to the view. It would look like `data: JSON.parse(<Promise>)`. Don't call that function in view. Instead call it in controller and assign the result to a scope variable to pass to view

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I made it like this `$scope.WebDataRocks = function () {
       servTotalIncomeReport.WebDataRocks($scope.Filter).then(function (d) {$scope.MyData = d.data;}, function (err) { });}` 
and the div is like this 
`<div wbr-pivot wbr-toolbar="true"  wbr-report="{ 'dataSource': { 'data':JSON.parse(MyData),'dataSourceType': 'json'}}" >
                </div>`
, i recognize that too many calls are made from this function and the pivot table doesn't work

Comment: Did you call `$scope.WebDataRocks()` in controller? Did you define  a default `myData` so it isn't undefined while waiting for promise to resolve?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also the api call appears in the network tab "chrome" more than 20 times, it just called once.
The Pivot table didn't appear

Comment: Sure you aren't calling it in the view? that is a bad thing to do. Angular will render that view numerous times until scope stabilizes

Comment: Yes I am sure, the view is like this
`<div wbr-pivot wbr-toolbar="true"  wbr-report="{ 'dataSource': { 'data':MyData,'dataSourceType': 'json'}}" ></div>`

Comment: The call is like this `$scope.WebDataRocks();`
at the bottom of the controller